# Preview API list does not match the installed SDKs in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a problem rendering a certain .xml layout in Android Studio. It displays:
"Unable to find the layout for Action Bar..."

Unfortunately, for this xml, the only available API level is 23, as seen in the figure. For other xmls I have available levels: 23, 21, 19, 17. The SDKs installed in SDK manager are: 23, 21, 19, 17, 15. The target SDK in manifest is set to 19, the minumum API is set to 17.

Why is just API 23 available for this single xml? Why does "Automatically Pick Best" also picks 23, although it is not able to render the layout?[image]

Comment: check your gradle file for appcompact librray version. make sure version is matched with compileSdkVersion

Comment: build.gradle says: android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2" ... compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0' ... } Also, the gradle file applies to the whole project, with many xmls, while just a single one is affected.

Comment: then change compile sdkversion to 23 or change buildtoolversion to 19.X.X

Comment: I changed buildtools to "19.1.0" but it did not help. How Android Studio decides which API is the best, and which are available for a given xml layout?